# create jar for webapp

Tags: java, web-applications, netbeans, jar

i'm using netbeans for writing a webapp + filter.

I want to generate a jar file (to place in tomcat/lib folder) for the sake of the filter.

when i compile the project, it generates war file.

is there a way to tell netbeans to generate a jar file instead?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to make the filter a jar, but if your reason is for re-use, then it should just be a separate project.

Comment: thanks man! i've been battling around it for too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a separate project to generate your .jar file. In that case also I think you have to create the .jar using terminal. You can't create a .jar file for a web project using netbeans IDE, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

You can add something like this to your build.xml:

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <jar destfile="${basedir}/dist/my_web_app.jar">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/build/web/WEB-INF/classes">

        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Which will build you a jar alongside your war.

EDIT: See Ravindra's answer below for a slight improvement to this method.

Answer (score 2):

An enhancement to @DeadPassive answer - You can get the web app name using the variable `${ant.project.name}`

```
<target name="-post-compile">
    <jar destfile="${basedir}/dist/${ant.project.name}.jar">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/build/web/WEB-INF/classes">
        </fileset>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe modify the build.xml used by netbeans, adding a copy task on the generated jar.